# Trigger to disallow inserting negative number to tables' column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my mssql database I need to create a trigger that will disallow inserting negative budget to projects table. I don't really know how can I do it. All kind of help will be appreciated!

```
CREATE TRIGGER budget on PROJ FOR INSERT
```

For all answers ommiting triggers - unfortunately I need to do this with trigger

Comment: You need to provide more information, at lest show us what did you try.

Comment: Well, you start with `CREATE TRIGGER`.  Have you done that?

Comment: all I can do is creating some trigger but don't know how to specify the instruction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for not using a `CHECK` constraint. However you can certainly implement that constraint with a trigger by checking if there is any new row that has negative budget and raising an error on that case.

```
CREATE TRIGGER projects_positive_budget ON projects 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE budget < 0)
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR('No negative budget is allowed', 16, -1);
      ROLLBACK;
      RETURN
   END
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a trigger for this.  SQL Server supports `check` constraints:

```
alter table projects add constraint chk_projects_budget check (budget >= 0);
```

Comment: This is by far a better option than using a `TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check multiple columns you can also

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD CONSTRAINT CH_CheckForNegative CHECK(Col1 >=0 AND Col2 >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to add constraint for checking acceptable integer values either positive or negative.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl](
        [F1] [int] NULL,
        [F2] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
     --To accept only positive numbers and 0
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Tbl] CHECK  (([F1]>=(0)))
    GO
    --To check constraint on the table
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tbl] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_Tbl]
    GO
    --To accept only negative numbers and 0
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tbl]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Tbl_1] CHECK  (([F2]<=(0)))
```

For more information you can check the link [Integer Constraint](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/44f5f523-0b78-4d95-aef8-4c6fcfcd3d50/non-zero-negative-integers-check?forum=transactsql)